# mongodb aggregate "$_id" return id as string not object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregate

mongodb aggregate "$_id" return id as string not objectID.
and when i send "$_id" of an document to a function, aggregation can't compare objectID and string. query below (return empty):

```
db.getCollection('general.users').aggregate([
    {
        $match: { _id: ObjectId("5a48894e4639fa6d7703c4f4") }
    },
    {
        $addFields: { creadit: fetchUserCreadit("$_id") }
    },
])
```

and that is some of my function :

```
const succPays = db.financial.successpayrequests.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: 
           { 
               $and:
                   [
                       {
                           userID: uid
                       }
                   ]
           } 
    },
    {
      $group:
        {
          _id: null,
          amountSum: { $sum: '$amount' }
        }
    }
]).toArray();
return  succPays;
```

when i send param in hardcode every thing is ok becuse param send as object (return not empty array).

```
db.getCollection('general.users').aggregate([
{
    $match: { _id: ObjectId("5a48894e4639fa6d7703c4f4") }
},
{
    $addFields: { creadit: fetchUserCreadit(ObjectId("5a48894e4639fa6d7703c4f4")) }
},
```

Comment: is aggregate pipeline returns `_id` as `String` or do you want to compare string id to object id in aggregation pipeline?

Comment: i want to compare string id to object id in aggregation pipeline or cast string to objectid.

Comment: you can't do this with aggregate pipeline, with map-reduce you can call user defined functions

Comment: i can call custom function in aggregate, but my problem is _id parameter sends to function ("$_id") as string not object, but when i use hard code to send it ( ObjectId(ac54adv5dv21adv5avd126) ) it's seems ok!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is order of execution of enclosed functions.   Javascript is calling `fetchUserCreadit` *before* it assembles the `$addFields` expression and passes the fully baked pipeline to `db.foo.aggregate()`.  Javascript sees `$_id` and just sends that as a string; it has no idea about MongoDB and indeed, at the point this is called, there is not even a pipeline going.  Here is a compact but similar demo of the problem.

```
function myFunc(id) {
  print("myFunc: got " + id);
  return db.foo.findOne({_id: id});
}

db.foo.aggregate([
{$match: { _id: ObjectId(s_oid1) }}
,{$addFields: {qq: myFunc("$_id")}}
                ]);
```